Handling of hardware errors / Single-event upset in enterprise systems
I'm reading more and more about Single-event upsets etc. and how e.g. Google, Meta etc. see them in their datacenters, even silent data corruption etc. Having worked on many enterprise systems (incl. banking etc.) running on standard software stacks (Java, spring boot, Oracle etc.) I've never seen that been given any thought. In the contexts where I've brought it up people look at you as if you are a conspiracy theorists. The places I've worked it seems the risk of that happening is treated as practically zero, no doubt due to the risk of other types of errors being much higher. Yet it can occur, and since it's not thought of the consequences are completely unpredictable: bit flips could cause texts/amounts to change, but they could also happen in pointers which could cause more complicated problems: Consider a police system working on the 'criminal record' of a given user. A pointer in a data structure flips and suddenly now points to an entry (e.g. crime) of another user etc. with everything seemingly OK (no mangled texts etc.).
I believe this should be given more thought. As far as I can tell it doesn't make sense to mitigate this at the low-level (defensive software techniques at method level) but maybe instead try to process all transactions on multiple systems to check that they end up in the same state. But this requires extraordinary care in how this is done especially since it is likely not acceptable to process everything serially and there are many sources that could affect processing (time stamps etc.).
Googling hasn't turned up much. It's mostly in critical microcontroller-level systems (e.g. breaking system in cars etc.) people care about these things, not enterprise systems. And then there's a lot on reproducible builds, but that's just one isolated case.
So here's the question: Are there any work done in dealing with these challenges in typical enterprise systems and in a way that can co-exist with how these systems are typically written and the frameworks used? And what is your impression of the current 'best practice' and level of awareness in this area?
